# SQL Alchemy relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've run into another problem with SQLAlchemy. I have a relationship that is suppose to cascade delete some data from my model declared like so :

```
parentProject = relationship(Project, backref=backref("OPERATIONS", cascade="all,delete"))
```

This works fine as long as the data is from the current session. But if I start a session , add some data then close. Start another session and try to delete data from the previous one , the cascade doesnt work. The initializer of the database is as follows:

```
if isDBEmpty:
    LOGGER.info("Initializing Database")
    session = dao.Session()
    model.Base.metadata.create_all(dao.Engine)
    session.commit()
    LOGGER.info("Database Default Tables created successfully!")
    dao.storeEntity(model.User(administrator_username, md5(administrator_password).hexdigest(), administrator_email, True, model.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR))
    LOGGER.info("Database Default Generic Values were stored!")
else:
    LOGGER.info("Database already has some data, will not be re-created at this startup!")
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something very basic here. Some help would be very appreciated.

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: It's a little hard to see what could be happening without the code.  Can you show some simple code that demonstrates the problem?  It would also be useful to see the code for your db model as well.

Comment: I am wondering if when you open a new session, you reload the objects you created in the old one, or just using the same references (variables). You should reload; if you do not, this might cause the issue you are having